# Facebook long-lived and short-lived access tokens, and their expirancy after offline_access removal

Tags: facebook, access-token

While reading Facebook's post regarding [offline_access permission removal](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), I was thoroughly confused by their reference to short-lived and long-lived access tokens.

[This page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) mentioned

> The duration for which a given access token is valid depends on how it
>   was generated

But I failed to find any further information.

Anyone has insights on how this determination process works in detail?

Comment: Which scenario are you using in your app? i think all but the weirdest edge cases are covered in that doc

Answer (score 8):

The access token your app gets for a [Client-Side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) is short lived (about 2 hours), but you can extend it and get a long lived token using the [new endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) with a **valid** access token.
In the [Handling Invalid/Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/) it says under *Desktop Web and Mobile Web apps which implement authentication with the Javascript SDK*:

> Calling FB.getLoginStatus() or ensuring status: true is set when you
>   call FB.init() means that the next time a user lands on your
>   application and is signed into Facebook, the authResponse object you
>   are passed as a result of those calls will contain a fresh, valid
>   access token.
>
> In this case, its simply the act of the user using your application
>   which implicitly generates a new access token.

If you use the [Server-Side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) flow then you will automatically get a long lived token (about 60 days) automatically.
When that expires you have to send the user to re-authenticate in the same flow (code exchanging).

You can of course use both methods and that way you can get a long lived token in the server and a short lived token in the client.

Comment: Any pointers under the following contexts?
Authentication in native Android apps
Authentication in native iOS apps
Authentication within a Page Tab on www.facebook.com
Authentication within a Canvas Page on apps.facebook.com

Comment: The [Handling Invalid and Expired Access Tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/) guide talks about all of that. Inside a page tab you can use the js sdk which makes it the same, in this context, as canvas app.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan. From your answer can I assume Android/iOs/Server-flow receives a long-lived token (60days), Client-flow/Page-tab/Canvas receives a short-lived token (few hours)?

Comment: I'm not sure at all regarding the ios/android, I haven't checked but I think that it's a short lived since there's an "extending the token" option.